# Where should maximum heap size be configured in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm, jvm-arguments

Under `Preferences -> Compiler -> Java Compiler` I notice that Additional Command line properties and maximum heap size can be configured.

[image]

For these to take effect, I restart IntelliJ. However, I still keep getting `Out of memory error` on one of my programs.

I also noticed the `idea.vmoptions` file where the settings still are:

```
~/Documents $ more /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12.app/bin/idea.vmoptions 
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

**Question**

I want to use `UseConcMarkSweepGC` and raise max heap size to 4gb. Where should I be doing this for it to take effect in IntelliJ? I am using Intellij12

Answer (score 0):

Just open file `idea.vmoptions` with TextEdit and change config as you like :)

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4G  // change this 
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC // and add this
```

Compiler options - it's options for execute javac.

But one question: Why you want so huge heap for Idea?

If you have OOM when you run project, try change Run options (not compiler and not IDE).